# Gatsby, hooks and fetching data from an API error "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function Table"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm trying to implement this table into my Gatsby app. It was working fine in React.js, however Gatsby doesn't want to agree with it and keeps giving the error TypeError: Object(...) is not a function.

This is my table component...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useTable, useFilters, useSortBy, useGlobalFilter } from "react-table";

const Table = ({ columns, data, plans, specials }) => {
  console.log(plans, "plan");
  console.log(specials, "special");

const [filterInput, setFilterInput] = useState("");
const [filterPlan, setFilterPlan] = useState("");
const [filterSpecial, setFilterSpecial] = useState("");

const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    setFilter
  } = useTable(
    {...
```

This is the return of the page I am rendering in gatsby...

```
 return (
    <>

      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          setUrl(api);
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
      ></form>


      {isError && <div>Something went wrong...</div>}
      {isLoading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <ul></ul>}

      {data && <Table columns={columns} data={data} plans={plans} specials={specials} />}
    </>
  );
}

export default search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out... This error is the result of not updating to the new react-table.